# Highlighting local maxima of an attribute in a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

I have two layers from the same track measured at a different time, and would like to highlight where they have moved the most.

I can use closet point function to work out regular separations along the line, and I can filter to remove trivial separations to a threshold value, eg below at 1.5m.  This leaves me with a layer formed from a set of lines at 1m intervals

What I would like to be able to do is highlight and label the single local maximum from each deviation, rather than all points, or all points over a threshold.

There is an attribute of all the separation distances along the line, and the lines are regularly acquired such that fid and acquisition time is constantly growing along the lines.  Is there an easy way to find local maxima?

[image: Two tracks with a set of separating lines]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxUJmx0eL2TuWvGD4SgNTXjFgpPm_F2c/view?usp=drivesdk.  Hope this works, very limited in how I can share data.